# Convert one object in another object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

I have an database result as shows in file:

[image: database results]

So I have input data as follows:

```
const input = [
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a',
        ProductStock_id: '0a701dbc-2661-4d67-b764-632cfb67334f',
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a',
        ProductStock_id: '15278807-794a-4727-9bcb-f7f68dfb4d41',
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a',
        ProductStock_id: '0ac9fcd7-73f0-47b1-8fbc-3948863e7a89',
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '65e013a7-c7b2-47cf-88b7-2ab2d9bcd191',
        ProductStock_id: null,
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '8f00dde6-2548-46a7-a480-37e86a3ca895',
        ProductStock_id: '1439dde4-d184-4c98-b0c4-6d3c88ce8496',
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: 'b48711b3-14b1-41ce-9f5f-4032297c1b8e',
        ProductStock_id: null,
    },
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '4e22378d-cf56-4806-bea2-5ba0b220d3eb',
        ProductStock_id: null,
    },
];
```

I'd like to convert input object into output object as follows:

```
const output = [
    {
        PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da',
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids: [
            {
                PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a',
                ProductStock_ids: [
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: '0a701dbc-2661-4d67-b764-632cfb67334f',
                    },
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: '15278807-794a-4727-9bcb-f7f68dfb4d41',
                    },
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: '0ac9fcd7-73f0-47b1-8fbc-3948863e7a89',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '65e013a7-c7b2-47cf-88b7-2ab2d9bcd191',
                ProductStock_ids: [
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: null,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '8f00dde6-2548-46a7-a480-37e86a3ca895',
                ProductStock_ids: [
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: '1439dde4-d184-4c98-b0c4-6d3c88ce8496',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: 'b48711b3-14b1-41ce-9f5f-4032297c1b8e',
                ProductStock_ids: [
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: null,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '4e22378d-cf56-4806-bea2-5ba0b220d3eb',
                ProductStock_ids: [
                    {
                        ProductStock_id: null,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Which should looks like on this image when folded:

[image: outout result]

And I don't know how to convert this way. I'm rather PHP developer, so doing this in JavaScript is hard for me.

I tried do this using some ways like three time iterate over this input object, searching uuid in arrays with no luck.

This input object can have multiple PurchaseInvoice_id which are connected with PurchaseInvoicePosition_id and with ProductStock_id.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it? What were the issues with your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the `Array.reduce` implementation of your question

Logic

- Loop through the input array.
- Check if there is already a node with the current `PurchaseInvoice_id` present in the `accumulator`
- If its not present, push the current node to `accumulator` in the desired pattern (Check Section 1 in the comment added in code)
- If its present (Section 2 in code comment), find whether there is a node with current `PurchaseInvoicePosition_id` in the `PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids` of the found node
- If that is not found (Section 3 in code comment), push your current `PurchaseInvoicePosition_id` and `ProductStock_id` to your accumulator.
- If that is found (Section 4 in code comment) push your `ProductStock_id` to the `ProductStock_ids` of the found node.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const input = [
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a', ProductStock_id: '0a701dbc-2661-4d67-b764-632cfb67334f', },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a', ProductStock_id: '15278807-794a-4727-9bcb-f7f68dfb4d41', },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a', ProductStock_id: '0ac9fcd7-73f0-47b1-8fbc-3948863e7a89', },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '65e013a7-c7b2-47cf-88b7-2ab2d9bcd191', ProductStock_id: null, },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '8f00dde6-2548-46a7-a480-37e86a3ca895', ProductStock_id: '1439dde4-d184-4c98-b0c4-6d3c88ce8496', },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: 'b48711b3-14b1-41ce-9f5f-4032297c1b8e', ProductStock_id: null, },
  { PurchaseInvoice_id: '8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da', PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: '4e22378d-cf56-4806-bea2-5ba0b220d3eb', ProductStock_id: null, },
];
const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const purchaseInvoiceNode = acc.find((item) => item.PurchaseInvoice_id === curr.PurchaseInvoice_id);
  if (purchaseInvoiceNode) {
    // Section 2
    const purchaseInvoicePositionNode = purchaseInvoiceNode.PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids.find((item) => item.PurchaseInvoicePosition_id === curr.PurchaseInvoicePosition_id);
    if(purchaseInvoicePositionNode) {
      // Section 4
      purchaseInvoicePositionNode.ProductStock_ids.push({
        ProductStock_id: curr.ProductStock_id,
      })
    } else {
      // Section 3
      purchaseInvoiceNode.PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids.push({
          PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: curr.PurchaseInvoicePosition_id,
          ProductStock_ids: [
            {
              ProductStock_id: curr.ProductStock_id
            }
          ]
        })
    }
  } else {
    // Section 1
    acc.push({
      PurchaseInvoice_id: curr.PurchaseInvoice_id,
      PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids: [
        {
          PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: curr.PurchaseInvoicePosition_id,
          ProductStock_ids: [
            {
              ProductStock_id: curr.ProductStock_id
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've adapted your solution in my code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call the operation you're performing `nestedGroups()`.  If you have an array of objects `arr`, and an ordered list of keys `key1`, `key2`, `key3` (etc.) of the elements of `arr`, then `nestedGroups(arr, key1, key2, key3)` will return an object whose key will be a pluralized (just adding `"s"`) version of `key1`, and whose value will be another array of groupings for the next key, and so on.  This is hard to describe in words, so I'll just show an example:

```
const ng = nestedGroups(
    [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5 }, { a: 4, b: 6 }],
    "a", "b"
);
/* const ng: { as: { a: number; bs: { b: number; }[]; }[]; } */

console.log(ng)
/* {
  "as": [
    {"a": 1, "bs": [{"b": 2}, {"b": 3}]},
    {"a": 4, "bs": [{"b": 5}, {"b": 6}]}
  ]
} */
```

If we can implement and strongly type `nestedGroups()`, then your output will look like:

```
const r = nestedGroups(input,
  "PurchaseInvoice_id", "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id", "ProductStock_id");
const output = r.PurchaseInvoice_ids;

/* const output: {
    PurchaseInvoice_id: string;
    PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids: {
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: string;
        ProductStock_ids: {
            ProductStock_id: string | null;
        }[];
    }[];
}[] */
```

which you can verify is the type you want.

---

First let's *implement* it and worry about the strong types later:

```
// implementation
function nestedGroups(arr: Record<string, any>[], ...keys: string[]): any {
    const [firstKey, ...restKeys] = keys;
    if (firstKey === undefined) return {};
    const retmap = new Map<any, any>();
    arr.forEach(v => {
        const val = v[firstKey];
        if (!(retmap.has(val))) retmap.set(val, []);
        retmap.get(val)!.push(v);
    });
    return {
        [firstKey + "s"]: Array.from(retmap.entries()).map(([k, v]) =>
            ({ [firstKey]: k, ...nestedGroups(v, ...restKeys) }))
    }
}
```

This is a recursive function which calls `nestedGroups()` inside itself unless the array of `keys` is empty.  An empty `keys` array results in an empty return object.  Otherwise, we use the first key `firstKey` to group the values in the array.  Here I'm using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the values, so each time we see a property value at `key1` that we've seen before, we push it onto the end of the array in that `Map`.  And finally, the returned object has a single pluralized `firstKey` property whose value is an array of objects composed of information from the `Map` and from the recursive subcall to `nestedGroups()`.

---

As for the typings, you'll end up needing [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) (to represent the recursion), [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (to pull the array of keys apart) and [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) (to add that `"s"` in the type system).

Let's define the `NestedGroups<T, K>` type to be the type of the return value of `nestedGroups(arr, ...keys)` when `arr` is of type `T[]` and `keys` is of type `K`:

```
type NestedGroups<T extends Record<K[number], Primitive>, K extends string[]> =
    K extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F extends string ? { [P in `${F}s`]:
        Array<Pick<T, F> & NestedGroups<T, Extract<R, string[]>> extends
            infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never>; } : never : {};

type Primitive = null | undefined | number | bigint | string | boolean | symbol;
```

We are [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to have keys in `K` and whose values at those keys are `Primitive` values (which we define as the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of JavaScript [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)) since those are [easily comparable as `Map` keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#key_equality).  (If the different values of, say, `PurchaseInvoicePosition_id` were *objects*, then they probably wouldn't compare as equal, and it would be hard to group by them.  Note that `"x" === "x"` is true but `{x: 1} === {x: 1}` is false).

Anyway, we will use `NestedGroups<T, K>` as the return value for `nestedGroups()`.  We can keep the original implementation and just declare that `nestedGroups` is an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a single call signature:

```
// call signature
function nestedGroups<T extends Record<K[number], Primitive>, K extends string[]>
    (arr: T[], ...keys: K): NestedGroups<T, K>;
```

---

Okay, time to test it on your `input`:

```
const r = nestedGroups(input, "PurchaseInvoice_id", "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id", "ProductStock_id")

const output = r.PurchaseInvoice_ids;

/* const output: {
    PurchaseInvoice_id: string;
    PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids: {
        PurchaseInvoicePosition_id: string;
        ProductStock_ids: {
            ProductStock_id: string | null;
        }[];
    }[];
}[] */

console.log(output);
/*
 [{
  "PurchaseInvoice_id": "8e54a096-568b-48d9-8461-826be53a32da",
  "PurchaseInvoicePosition_ids": [
    {
      "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id": "44edfd7f-bc9e-4155-ad5c-5dace9c7c31a",
      "ProductStock_ids": [
        {
          "ProductStock_id": "0a701dbc-2661-4d67-b764-632cfb67334f"
        },
        {
          "ProductStock_id": "15278807-794a-4727-9bcb-f7f68dfb4d41"
        },
        {
          "ProductStock_id": "0ac9fcd7-73f0-47b1-8fbc-3948863e7a89"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id": "65e013a7-c7b2-47cf-88b7-2ab2d9bcd191",
      "ProductStock_ids": [
        {
          "ProductStock_id": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id": "8f00dde6-2548-46a7-a480-37e86a3ca895",
      "ProductStock_ids": [
        {
          "ProductStock_id": "1439dde4-d184-4c98-b0c4-6d3c88ce8496"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id": "b48711b3-14b1-41ce-9f5f-4032297c1b8e",
      "ProductStock_ids": [
        {
          "ProductStock_id": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PurchaseInvoicePosition_id": "4e22378d-cf56-4806-bea2-5ba0b220d3eb",
      "ProductStock_ids": [
        {
          "ProductStock_id": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
*/
```

Yes, that's the right type and the right output value.

---

There you go.  The strong typing here might be overkill for your use case, but since you're asking about TypeScript and not just JavaScript, it might be useful to include it.  If all you care about is the output value and not really the type, then you can forgo the typing and just leave it something wide like `any`.  It's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAdgVwBtCoAfKfXAEwgDMFcIqy98kAjCOF9hAcwbAWAZ2CJcfHgHsphCAENcIkB1kBuALAAoUJCgA5CKKYBxOFPxhhAHgAqUCAA9gEasKgAlCAGMpcKtYA0gDaBBxcALoANLCIKGiYAHwxgQ7OrlTuouJ8wRGJUFjaUFCpTi5uUMEMtFxQAGIxAHQtNXUeEVAA-A1pFZlQ2QySPQDeVTBQDFAABgAko-UAvsIzEQBcxSVQAIJwcPIg1jAI3gDWdjH1BQBkBkYuVGYWVpdQAKLOB97A1h4xQwkeUSBXKGWEW22U1wtW4AHlulBxsFJtMzhAQFJaFA4RscSjOksoOs8BBMHBEmooESSYxycSkUtNFpaJQfggpEpGMYnuZLDZ7GDKl5fP4gqE2Jw4NFYshUBgIMlSn1wYMxMNgVsABTyfYk2x5ZotdEgYQkwIAShJhh5z35b0ClO02lZuHZnNJtr5Vh1es8Pj8AUBfBiihAiUNUBaTRNZrVOTyFqRW18uFEVXocFEgQxRqacAeOdNnRwseZJQQ2K1mezGMKWBwlBo9EYVCTBeA+DgSlGTJTnPTHaQ8jAhVJAHcoABZEfWMOh3DhrUW8tQXVwJq0PzveTeAAWWvQhQKo0hUFT6fQ8hIOHQwRrwCLEVXFarAEItUOR009-JhIfrwtICoC-MAmmECBgAAwgYkTF8QMg4cwL4SDoItN8mjAfBhAPdAVy2JZ8K0EoOy7Hsz3vBAs0fOsAGooAAImEBi8T2A4QE3cwkE-RDv1cdUjGXC0miQrUtWCM4YnQCIkywRIzxKLVkQfJ8SUkqMWm5R47R9dA8wLWtTSTQiLQI7QlmdLQLyECQxy00xvX-LZgnGeQSQARhidgSQAJmpGJXI8rySQAZn8pE1xJAAWYKoAAVnCwKoBiqBvKgAA2aloi2Bj5AYmIGPYBjtCIgB6AAqc8BxsvgSVcuMkrCKUqXYBrUtpSUuCpJY8m63rqSgcrSu0C9ZAgJpCCkPgtQkUytAq5NiMYv8GJJYIz1GXLVqgTzGNa7aXMK7afKWAKjtCpYIlOjatuigr9rWzaipJOLTqRc6MsuiyloiczBuGrQRuq6EsKEHB1qW08lpKGAu33P8IAASVwdApFOCAAH0ECoEkAHIAA4IDiqL5AABgATnSgBaOL0vx9gqai-GqHJqn8ai9L3LZnz0s4OKQvkEKfKoeRcaiM9YbgeGIOR1H0ZgKRhHlTksZxqBcaiqKmFoKgAHZaCp9hvHJiBGfcuK4qp+QqDi7waZF7wIHJ7xde8EL3NF8XodiKQqHwH4AGVgCkc5Vbx0n5F10n3KoI2qZ5znGaodLdcN3X0qiqn0qF7xaHYFOQpCqLaDFgivZKKGoUl6WkZRtHHbD9XCeJsnKZpumGaZlm2Y5rn8Z5vmBaFkXS+96vfxluv5cV5XcEbjWtaoHX9cN43Tai83Let237d3J2Xbdj3R6r8w-cD4PQ+xvHzZ83X8fx0nU918mScZ3Xb6p8mjYZ2h9bppf2BRSoBvY+-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-rQOKBsoqkyFj5cmrt4WE2Wfw8+wjG7ZJgmXcBhiXnuJKXjD5yCvnWJqX8nBg9GnAsgaC15EAIUcm8aUrWPkfKTOZlTXOtN0Gk2ppweQoS4rsDJiEnyPSQoQHYMS1ZpKNkdRyVSrQz5LLWRAnZB4DkXj-gYKDXJDEoFFNgarfKjF7VgunpQgVTqCorLSeszJVAGJERNRYYAoMxwbldby1WwhmTaAWsG-AobE11RpcYuljdgzwUjXS-l1DMgpu9iC1pDr3WdPgZmhSkCSXpLJdjBqlaoQw2rX6jN6pbLkApfBKEPUjXex7cyHt-1jUDjGhNKaWoQ2gzKuVYoLkcrZuKU6kkDFGWWKqT82xdSAX4JFvledPKc2eM9XWg6G1K12oPe0o9ebtoMU1nQlejD16b1YTvDhe9nbcI9nuwtLrm0ZOjae39FcG3bDtf+2tAbl0RyjjHOOCcuZAJTmnDOWcc55wLkXWgxVgN5MbdsJ5+G-3aprRs29N874Pyfi-eQb8P5f28D-P+zM85AI3jhojeGiOEfw+BkjLbsa3rEeTCRUiZFyIUUouOqimYzPVVonRHGiPfXw79PtzTFq8YXeC69grb2+P8e5QJErdYhLCQbe+7AokxOFgxhJSSf1aYgxs5ia1QM8cbXx31AHBN6sIKBlTja1Pdo0x5i9xa3UeI9Te5d+Num7P6YM4Zoz5DjKppM6Zsz5k6Lio5zzPq1k+cyEBzjHmoRecK5B8j2zya7P2e5Q5UVjmGzORcq53gbnTKipTJT+HAtQmC9sfRUIwvadLZC3ze0mawvhYi5FiH3JopE5ixmOKRX4u8ISiAeXysFZ1f61zVR3OgZKBV-bS7WDEAC5WwbJRhsEfPWNqLZaoOMWFaKu+VAJUYupuM2VCgFVKtJiqtVGqdtgb26Rg7JXuMneI95qrfnru-tu9SLYamhrDrTKOya00GKOAYvWHA+PA1QFKqVKAYh8AQCBtjuQY7prjEcB5AaDYcBM5Z4RMnFPaDXggkAA)

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't adapt your version because of types. I chosen and adapt solution from Nitheesh.